# Center horizontally and veritcally a React component inside a div tag using CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, center

I'm trying to display a React Spinner component centered horizontally and vertically in the screen, after search and read different similar answers, for example this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically), I could center it horizontally, currently my code is this:

```
import ClipLoader from "react-spinners/BounceLoader";

function Spinner() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        flexDirection: "row",
      }}
    >
      <ClipLoader color="#52bfd9" size={100} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Spinner;
```

The result I'm getting is this:

[image: center horizontally]

However, I'm dealing how to center it vertically, the nearest I get from the solution is this code:

```
<div style={{ verticalAlign: 'middle', position:'absolute', top: '50%', left: '50%', marginTop: '-100px', marginLeft: '-250px' }}>
```

But it is not centered it vertically and horizontally, please take a look at the next image:

[image: notcentered]

My question is: do you have any recommendation how to center vertically and horizontally the div tag and the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options to center the contents of a div. In your first example, you set the div to flex and set all of the alignment properties, but you're missing a height. By default the div is going to be `height: auto;`. So , it is centering the content vertically, but the div is the height of the item. Adding this css to your wrapping div should fix it:

```css
height: 100vh;
```

You could also do this very easily with grid:

```css
div {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    place-items: center;
}
```

Both of these do the same thing. You just need to add a height and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Someone beat me to it, but yeah your first approach is fine. You just need to specify the height for your flex container.

**Demo/Example**

https://codesandbox.io/s/centered-spinner-95874e

Answer (score 1):

```
<div
  className="spinner"
>
  <ClipLoader color="#52bfd9" size={100} />
</div>
```

and in your css file do this :

```
.spinner{
 height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```